# After changing the image to numpy array, I want to import only 1 channel

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I took some images and replaced them with numpy array.

The image is a RGB image.

The converted numpy array is of size (256, 256, 3).

I wanted to import only the Y channel after I switched this RGB image to YCbCr.

What I want is an array of size (256,256, 1).

So I used [:,:, 0] in the array.

However, I have now become a two-dimensional image as shown in the code below.

I created an array of (256, 256, 1) size with 15 lines of code.

But I failed to see it again as an image.

Below is my code.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

img = Image.open('test.bmp') # input image 256 x 256
img = img.convert('YCbCr')
img.show()
print(np.shape(img))         # (256, 256, 3)

arr_img = np.asarray(img)
print(np.shape(arr_img))     # (256, 256, 3)

arr_img = arr_img[:, :, 0]
print(np.shape(arr_img))     # (256, 256)

arr_img = arr_img.reshape( * arr_img.shape, 1 )
print(np.shape(arr_img))     # (256, 256, 1)

pi = Image.fromarray(arr_img)
pi.show                      # error : TypeError: Cannot handle this data type
```

When I forcibly changed a two-dimensional image into a three-dimensional image,

The image can not be output.

I want to have a purely (256, 256, 1) sized array.

Y image of the channel!

I tried to use arr_img = arr_img [:,:, 0: 1] but I got an error.

How can I output an image with only Y (256,256,1) size and save it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single-channel image should actually be in 2D, with shape of just (256, 256).  Extracting out the Y channel is effectively the same as having a greyscale image, which is just 2D.  Adding the third dimension is causing the error because it is expecting just the two dimensions.

If you remove the reshape to (256, 256, 1), you will be able to save the image.

**Edit**:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

img = Image.open('test.bmp') # input image 256 x 256
img = img.convert('YCbCr')
arr_img = np.asarray(img) # (256, 256, 3)
arr_img = arr_img[:, :, 0] # (256, 256)
pi = Image.fromarray(arr_img)
pi.show()

# Save image
pi.save('out.bmp')
```

Comment: Could you please give me such a detailed code?

I have replaced the 15 lines of code with [arr_img = np.reshape (arr_img, (256,256,1))].

But the same error occurs.

Comment: I wanted the shape of (256 256 1), but I can not do it.

Thank you, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
arr_img_1d = np.expand_dims(arr_img, axis=1)
```

[Here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html) is the numpy documentation for the `expand_dims` function.